# if menu item exists show or hide link with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke

I would like to check if my menu contains the menu item "Admin".

Admin is the name of the parent menu item. When the user is logged in they can see the admin menu.

My menu css path looks like this:

```
div.toppane div.logopane div.menupane ul.sf-menu li a
```

If it does then I would like to display the following link

```
<a href="/en-us/aboutus/abgroup.aspx?ctl=logoff" id="Logoff" />Logoff</a>
```

But if "admin" isnt present then I need to show this link:

```
<a href="/en-us/aboutus/abgroup.aspx?ctl=login" id="Login" />Login</a>
```

Comment: This really is the kind of thing you should be doing server side, assuming 'Admin' refers to some kind of login authorised account.

Comment: admin is a menu item. Part of my DNN installation is broken. and the redirect seems to work. I just need to tidy it up. Admin is the name of the parent menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM structure is missing in your question! **:(**, so I'll give it a try...

```
if ($('div.toppane div.logopane div.menupane ul.sf-menu')
    .has('ul.sf-menu li a')){
     $('#Logoff').show();
}
else{
     $('#Login').show();
}
```

Or what the Admin thing looks like, just put it in the `has`...

---

**Update:**

> "admin" is a string value.. So assuming i need to check for the value in the menu?

Use `is` + `:has` + `:containes`.

```
if ($('div.toppane div.logopane div.menupane ul.sf-menu')
     .is(':has(a:contains(Admnin))')) {`
```

Comment: "admin" is a string value.. So assuming i need to check for the value in the menu?

Comment: @sp-1986. :`.contains("admin")`

Comment: @sp-1986. Can you please show us how your menu looks like the "admin" string is there?

Comment: @sp-1986. the full DOM struture please... and is it `admin` or `Admin`? it's important!

Comment: @sp-1986. I was little off. check the update and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqT48/2/)

Comment: thanks buddy, but really strange on the actual website Login seems to show regardless of whether admin is there or not.

Comment: fixed it.. i removed the A from my css path, i could see you were checking that in the contains! thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be using jQuery for determining navigation items and instead this should be done server side. What happens if i disable Javascript? It would be better to have an IF statment checking if 'admin' is set and changing the link as required.